# Email send speed impacted by Json API call

Tags: api, ampscript, json, microsites

Here's what's happening:

- The emails contain a microsite url appended with several variables that pass to the microsite via httppost (was httpget)
- The microsite captures the variables and their values and uses javascript to make a post API call and capture the response of the call
- The microsite also parses the json from the API and stores the API values in a data extension
- The email then does a lookup to the parsed hotel data and pulls the values into the email
- This can happen up to 3 times per email send

The reason I am using the microsite, is because there is no BuildRowsetFromJson ampscript function, and ET thought this would be a more elegant solution that trying to parse out the variables and values with substrings.

At this point, I've gone into the email code and:

- Removed superfluous code/lookups
- Optimized the existing code
- Moved the httppost inline with the for loops that build the html
- Changed it from an httpget to httppost in the email, because I am not actually requiring a response from the microsite. I just need to send the data and let the microsite handle the API call and parsing. Changing it to post seems like it is actually faster, but now we have the socket exception error.

I need to get the send speeds up. I feel like I have tried everything with the exception of trying to move the API call into the email and parse the json response with substrings. I think this would be a drain on resource as well.

Is it a resource limitation? Is there a better way? Should I throttle the sends?

Comment: What's the point of the API calls again?  To pull in external data specific to each email or subscriber?  If you could add some details on that, it might help us provide you with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have SFMC Support enable [Script Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) and have the first step in your automation be a SSJS script that does all of the API calls you need in preparation for your email.  The emails would then just lookup the data from the Data Extensions storing the data retrieved.

I'm a big fan of moving data wrangling out of the email scripting and into SSJS or [Query Activities](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

Comment: Hello Adam - I've heard of these Script Activities, but I've heard they use a lot of resource, and they can be detrimental to the account. Have they improved? How fast would it process 50K API calls?